# How can I get GDB to tell me what address caused a segfault?

Tags: c, gdb

I'd like to know if my program is accessing NULL pointers or stale memory.

The backtrace looks like this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x2b0fa4c8 (LWP 1333)]
0x299a6ad4 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x299a6ad4 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0058e900 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

With GDB 7 and higher, you can examine the `$_siginfo` structure that is filled out when the signal occurs, and determine the faulting address:

```
(gdb) p $_siginfo._sifields._sigfault.si_addr
```

If it shows `(void *) 0x0` (or a small number) then you have a NULL pointer dereference.

Comment: (gdb) p $_siginfo
$1 = void
I guess siginfo isn't supported on this architecture :(

Comment: Use `ptype $_siginfo` to see what else is in the struct.

Answer (score -6):

Run your program under GDB. When the segfault occurs, GDB will inform you of the line and statement of your program, along with the variable and its associated address.

You can use the "print" (p) command in GDB to inspect variables. If the crash occurred in a library call, you can use the "frame" series of commands to see the stack frame in question.

Comment: @nornagon: The `bt` command will show you a backtrace, which will let you see where you were in your own code when the fault happened.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's still no help -- it was in a library function call with several arguments, and I don't know which of those arguments is causing a segfault.

Comment: put watchs on those which could be wrong; put bp before the place you suspect sigfault could happen, and step instr by instr watching important vars...

Comment: @nornagon: Your backtrace is suspicious - you probably have stack corruption before calling your arguments. If stepping through the code ("n" and "s") doesn't reveal the problem, it is time to break out valgrind.